# Aliased git command fails, running it in the shell succeeds. Why?

Tags: git, shell, alias

Running this
`$ git commit --amend --no-edit`

results in successful merge

Now adding an alias

```
alias gam="git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

Now running..

`$ gam`

results in

```
fatal: Stray .git/rebase-apply directory found.
Use "git am --abort" to remove it.
```

This happens every time..

Why does running the same command in an alias cause an issue?

Comment: How did you add the alias?

Comment: ...it's not clear if that's a git alias or a shell alias (though the format given in the question implies the latter). If you added it as a shell alias, what does `set -x; gam; set +x` log?

Comment: (As a side note: [A near-universal answer to folks in the freenode #bash channel](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias) asking about problems with aliases has been, for more than a decade, "if you need to ask, use a function instead" -- not that any of the differences should be relevant in this particular case; but if you're having trouble with a shell alias, a good first step is to redefine it as a function).

Comment: The error hints at an error while running `git am` (not your `git commit ...` command), so my blind guess would be some other alias or function takes precedence over yours. +1 to "How did you add the alias ?" and `set -x; gam; set +x` ; more generally : debug your setup. You may try git aliases : `git config alias.cam 'commit --amend --no-edit'` -- you would then type `git cam`